# How to prevent duplicate shortcut creation in Android?

Tags: android

Some Android devices always create a shortcut for each app that is installed. Then, if my code also creates a shortcut there a duplication. On the other hand, some devices don't create a shortcut and it should be created programmatically.

I did go over any advice I found and:
1. I do use `myIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);`
2. And I did make sure I don't run this code twice using `SharedPreferences`

I still get duplicates and I don't wish to use:

> uses-permission
>   android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>

As it seems like bad practice and is ugly.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this to prevent duplicate shortcuts -

```
if(!getSharedPreferences(Utils.APP_PREFERENCE, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(Utils.IS_ICON_CREATED, false)){
    addShortcut();
    getSharedPreferences(Utils.APP_PREFERENCE, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(Utils.IS_ICON_CREATED, true);
}
```

Comment: As I said, I did that and that won't work. Since some phones already added a shortcut for the app before it was even opened. 

This code would add a second shortcut but won't add a third.